# How to use the symbol `~`?

Tags: css

I will want to understand how to use the symbol `~` in CSS?

In this example below, why `Spain` and `Italy` are in yellow color?

[image]

Thank you very much.

```css
div ~ p {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <p>Belgium</p>
   <div>
      <p>French</p>
   </div>
   <p>Spain</p>
   <p>Italy</p>
</div>
```

Comment: You may have to read more about selectors in css ...

Comment: Hi. The tilde selector select all elements after. So here it will select all the p after the div (at the same level). 
https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/css/what-does-the-css-tilde-selector-mean.html